# Programador de tareas no ejecuta tarea, porque no encuentra ruta del archivo cmd.exe desde archivo .bat el que ejecuta script python?

Tags: python, windows10

Cree un pequeño script en python el cual se tiene que ejecutar de forma diaria. Al ejecutarlo manual no hay problema ya que hace lo que necesito, pero al tratarlo de programar de forma automática es donde empieza el problema.

Con el Programador de tareas de Windows, abro un .bat el cual al cargar me abre en `C:\windows\system32` pero al ejecutarlo de forma directa del archivo .bat me abre en `C:\Usuarios\(miusuario)\.spyder-py3` (tengo instalado Anaconda) entonces, al final, Windows dice que no puede encontrar la ruta de donde esta el script de python

Ya cree las variables de entorno, para el usuario y para sistema, pero lo único que hace es que al abrir cmd e ingresar el nombre del script en python lo ejecuta de forma automática sin tener el ambiente Anaconda abierto.

El tema es que si lo hago por el programador de tareas de Windows, me abre el cmd desde su ruta `C:\windows\system32`, por lo que es imposible programarlo automático.

Estoy pensando en crear un .exe o un servicio de Windows, ¿saben como poder indicarle al cmd que me abra desde donde ejecuto todo?

Probé en el programador de tareas cambiando usuario, no ejecuta la tarea, agregando argumentos, tampoco levanta, si saben de algo me avisan por favor.

Este es la ruta donde abre al hacer doble clic en el archivo:

```
C:\Users\epavez.PRUEBAS01\.spyder-py3>call C:\Users\epavez.PRUEBAS01\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\epavez.PRUEBAS01\anaconda3
(base) C:\Users\epavez.PRUEBAS01\.spyder-py3>rem Run a python script in that environment
(base) C:\Users\epavez.PRUEBAS01\.spyder-py3>python Envio_vencimientos_contratos_x_wsp_TyPv2.py
```

Esto me aparece cuando lo ejecuto del **Programador de Tareas de Windows**:

```
C:\Windows\system32>call C:\Users\epavez.PRUEBAS01\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\epavez.PRUEBAS01\anaconda3 
(base) C:\Windows\system32>
rem Run a python script in that environment 
(base) C:\Windows\system32>python Envio_vencimientos_contratos_x_wsp_TyPv2.py python: can't open file 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\Envio_vencimientos_contratos_x_wsp_TyPv2.py': 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour], para empezar. Y vaya, has escrito esto sin respirar. Podrías poner algunos puntos y dividirlo en párrafos para que resulte más legible. No me queda claro si el script se ejecuta bien con solo salir a la línea de comandos? Tienes un bat que lo ejecute?

Comment: Asi es, el script al ejecutarlo directo desde anaconda o al hacer doble clic en el archivo.py, abre cmd de forma automatica y ejecuta el archivo sin problemas, lo que pude ver es un problema con el usuario y la ruta donde abre el cmd, la cual no puedo encontrar como cambiar o decirle que me abra el cmd desde el perfil usuario, ya que lo abre como admin y ahi es donde se marea.

Comment: Ya pude leerlo de nuevo, después de la edición. Veo que si tienes un bat. Si el único problema es la ruta de inicio, en el programador de tareas puedes indicarla. En Actions, el parámetro "Start In (optional)" que en español podría ser "Iniciar en (opcional)" indica la carpeta de inicio de la ejecución del programa.

Comment: Debes estar consciente que si haces doble clic sobre el script, este no se ejecuta directamente (ya que no es un ejecutable), sino que el sistema lanza el programa que esté registrado para esa extensión, que hará una serie de acciones y finalmente lanzará el interprete de python.  Lo ideal sería que tengas un bat que sea capaz de ejecutar el script desde la línea de comandos.

Comment: Por favor, no dejes código en comentarios... no es el lugar adecuado para eso. En su lugar, [edit] la pregunta y ve completándola y/o perfeccionandola. Un saludo.

Comment: Código y mensajes de error EN la pregunta, no en los comentarios por favor. Los comentarios son para las aclaraciones que los demás pidan, tú ve a [edit] y responde añadiendo info.

Comment: Por lo que puedo ver, si logra lanzar el interprete de python. Puedes agregar un comando `cd` o `pushd` al bat, para asegurarte de estar en la carpeta correcta y no depender de la carpeta donde se lance el bat. o bien puedes modificar el parámetro de la ruta de inicio en el programador de tareas. Creo que de ambas va a funcionar.

Comment: @jachguate, tenias razón, con el comando que me mencionaste pude hacer que me abriera bien el CMD, en la ruta especificada y ya no arroja el error de archivo no encontrado, mi fuerte no es precisamente programación dentro de la informática, así que se agradece mucho la ayuda y disposición.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución para la pregunta fue la que me entrego *@jachguate*,

El comando PUSHD me ayudó para que CMD se pudiera ejecutar en una ruta especifica, y así poder encontrar el archivo en python el cual necesitaba que me lanzara.

Este es el código empleado por si a alguien mas le sirve:

```
pushd C:\Users\PRUEBAS01\.spyder-py3
@CALL "C:\Users\PRUEBAS01\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" base
python C:\Users\PRUEBAS01\.spyder-py3\Envio_vencimientos_contratos_x_wsp_TyPv2.py
timeout /T 30 /NOBREAK
taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe
```

La mayoría de los errores del por que el programador de tareas no ejecuta el archivo python es que CMD no sabe se que es python ni que es un archivo .py, por lo que en el archivo .bat que se crea para que sea lanzado el archivo .py, hay que pasar todos los parámetros necesarios para que se ejecute cmd, entregarle el ambiente en el cual funcionara python, y activar python, con eso no debería haber problemas.

Muchas Gracias. Saludos

Comment: Te ayudo poniendo el código de la respuesta EN la respuesta ;) Puedes aceptarla dentro de unas horas para que quede marcada y otros sepan que es una pregunta con solución disponible!

Comment: Te pasaste con esa edición @Alfabravo, estoy recién aprendiendo a ocupar la plataforma, ya que las otras veces solo ingresaba para ver respuestas, ahora ya estoy viendo el modo edición para que quede todo mas ordenado, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Es una buena pregunta, con una buena respuesta. Merece dejarla bien ordenada para que le sirva a muchas personas más ;)

Comment: +1 Enhorabuena resolviste el problema. Diría que en ese bat ya no hace falta poner la ruta completa en la llamada a activate y la ejecución del script. Podrías usar rutas relativas, lo que lo haría un poco más legible y permitiría, además, un mantenimiento más fácil a la hora de cambiar la ruta en el futuro.